# Stubbing a dictionary in Rhino.Mocks

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, rhino-mocks, stub

I have a read-only dictionary on a dependency that I'd like to be able to stub with return values, and check that assignments to it have happened.

I was hoping that Rhino.Mocks would create an empty dictionary for me by default, but unfortunately it doesn't. Since it is read-only, I can't create a new dictionary and assign it to that property.

I was hoping to be able to stub it instead. From what I understand, the C# syntax for this would looking something like this:

```
m.Stub(x => x.myProperty).Return("abc");
```

So I was hoping that this would work for VB:

```
m.Stub(sub(x) x.myProperty).Return("abc");
```

But it doesn't (compiler error). Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'm open to the Expect/Verify syntax if it can accomplish this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Function` will do the trick:

```
m.Stub(Function(x) x.myProperty).Return("abc")
```

If you want to verify whether `myProperty` got called you could use `Expect` instead of `Stub`:

```
m.Expect(Function(x) x.myProperty).Return("abc")

// Some code here

m.VerifyAllExpectations()
```

Comment: Yea, that worked. Silly me for not thinking of at least trying that. Thanks!